# C++ range based for loop, is the container copied?

Tags: c++, for-loop

In C++, it is allowed to iterate over every element of a container (let's take a vector for instance), like in

```
vector<CustomObject> container;
//push back some objects in container

for(CustomObject obj : container){
    //process obj
}
```

I have a question about the "for" behavior: 
is container copied to be used in the for or accessed by reference?

Comment: You mean whole container copied? Why would it be like that? What should happen with the temporary copy afterwards? Discarded? So performance hit without any gain? No, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The container is not being copied. It's being accessed by reference. However, the `CustomObject` is being copied for each loop. The compiler may optimize away the copy, but that is not guaranteed.

To prevent the copying of `CustomObject`in this example, you'd do this: `for(CustomObject& obj : container)`

Comment: Should be `const CustomObject&` unless modification of the values is desired.

Answer (score 0):

The container is not copied. However, every element within it is copied. You can change this by specifying it using the ampersand. That is:

```
for (CustomObject &obj : container) {
     // Process obj
}
```

Usually the best decision when dealing with large containers.