# Printing out all books in my vector after doing pushback

Tags: c++

I have attempted to create a program where the user types books that will then be stored into a bookshelf. When the user types "DONE" the entries must end.

I want to get the following ouputs:

```
Welcome to your digital library!

Enter a book you would like to add: 
  Enter name: Harry Potter
  Enter author: Me
  Enter pages: 313

Enter a book you would like to add: 
  Enter name: Lord of the rings
  Enter author: Tolkien
  Enter pages: 412

Enter a book you would like to add: 
  Enter name: DONE

The following books are available in your bookshelf:

1. Harry Potter written by Me. Pages: 313
2. Lord of the rings written by Tolkien. Pages: 412
```

But instead I only get the first inputted book so I will only get:

```
The following books are available in your bookshelf:
    
    1. Harry Potter written by Me. Pages: 313
```

Why is that? I do a push_back for every get(book) and after my while loop is finished I print out all the books in a valid for loop. What's wrong with my program?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Book_Type{
    
    string name;
    string author;
    int pages;
};

bool get (Book_Type & book)
{
    
    cout << endl << "Enter a book you would like to add: " << endl
         << setw(14) << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin,book.name);
    
    if (book.name == "DONE")
    {   
        cout << endl;
        return false;
    }
    
    cout << setw(16) << "Enter author: ";
    getline(cin,book.author);
    
    cout << setw(15) << "Enter pages: ";
    cin >> book.pages;
    cin.ignore(1);
    
    return true;

}

void add (vector<Book_Type> & book_shelf,
          Book_Type const & book)
{
    book_shelf.push_back(book);
}



void put (vector<Book_Type> const & book_shelf,
          Book_Type const & book)
{
    int num {};
    
    cout << "The following books are available in your bookshelf:" << endl << endl;
    
    for (Book_Type book : book_shelf)
    {
        num++;
        
        cout << num << ". " << book.name 
             << " written by " << book.author
             << ". Pages: " << book.pages << endl;
    }
}




int main()
{
    Book_Type book {};
    vector<Book_Type> book_shelf {};
    
    cout << "Welcome to your digital library!" << endl;
    
    while (get(book))
    {
        get(book);
        add(book_shelf,book);
    }
    
    put(book_shelf,book);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: `for (Book_Type book : book_shelf)` you may want to use `for (const Book_Type& book : book_shelf)` related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387535/c-range-based-for-loop-is-the-container-copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387535/c-range-based-for-loop-is-the-container-copied)

Comment: I have already attempted doing that, but it still gives the same outputs. I don't really see how that would have an affect on the output anyways but I'm a newbie so who knows :P

Comment: It would not fix the problem. I have not debugged so not exactly sure of the problem.

Comment: My for loop is valid, because I have used this kind of loop before to print out all contents in a vector. I just dont know why in this scenario, it wont work.

Comment: The reason I commented about the range based for loop is it can cause an unneeded copy of every object as it iterates. It will work but is inefficient unless the compiler optimizes out the copy. The current answer found and solved your bug.

Comment: Danger: Don't forget to test the inputs for a successful read and conversion. `cin >> book.pages;` will fail if the user has finger trouble (or is a malicious actor) and the program will continue unaware. Errors you don't check for quickly become bugs you need to find and fix, so it's better to detect and handle the errors the first time around. Slight danger with `cin.ignore(1);`. It ignores exactly one character, so if the user inputs "1234 " and then hits enter, `ignore` will consume the space and leave the newline in the stream.

Answer (score 6):

```
while (get(book))
{
    get(book);
    add(book_shelf,book);
}
```

This looks like you call `get(book)` twice, but only add every other book to the book shelf. That way you would lose half the books.

Comment: Good point. Remove the: `get(book);` and leave the `while (get(book))`

Comment: For the OP: This should have been found out with a very quick debugging session.